# Django ModelForm Meta

Tags: python, django

I want create a ModelForm class where model is a parameter passed from the view.(i want a dynamic form, so i can create all forms using the same class ObjectForm by just changing model value in Meta) :

```
class ObjectForm(ModelForm):

    model_name = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model_name = kwargs.pop('model_name ')
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.get_model('core', model_name )
        exclude = ("societe")
```

An error is occured and say that model_name  is not a global field.
Please help me on this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem is that the class (and the Meta class) are processed at *compile time*, not when you instantiate your ObjectForm. at compile time, the model name is unknown. creating classes dynamically is possible, but a bit more complicated. as luck has it, the django devs have done the hard work for you:

```
>>> from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
>>> modelform_factory(MyModel)
<class 'django.forms.models.MyModelForm'>
```

**update**

So you want something like

```
def my_view(request):
    # ...
    MyForm = modelform_factory(MyModel)
    form = MyForm(request.POST) #  or however you would use a 'regular' form
```

Comment: the return value is the form (class)

Answer (score 3):

Well, your basic error is that you are accessing `model_name` as a local variable, rather than as a model instance. That's fairly basic Python.

But even once you've fixed this, it still wouldn't work. The Meta class is evaluated at define time, by the form metaclass, rather than at runtime. You need to call `forms.models.modelform_factory` - you can pass in your modelform subclass to the factory, if you want to define some standard validation and/or fields.

```
form_class = modelform_factory(MyModel, form=MyModelForm)
```